# Aggregating data in a dictionary structure to return a list of 3 tuples with averages

Tags: python, dictionary

The `stats1` function takes a `dict` argument and returns list of 3-tuples containing a `str` (a provider), an `int` (the number of services he/she provides), and a `float` (the average level of expertise). The result must be sorted by the names of the providers. Calling `stats1(db1)` returns:

```
[('Al', 2, 1.5), ('Bob', 2, 2.0), ('Carol', 3, 1.3333333333333333)]
```

Note that Al performs 2 services, whose average level of expertise is 1.5 (dog-walking at level 2 and painting at level 1).

```
db1 = {
    ('Al', 'dog-walking'): 2,
    ('Al', 'painting'): 1,
    ('Bob', 'dog-walking'): 1,
    ('Bob', 'knife-sharpening'): 3,
    ('Carol', 'cleanup'): 1,
    ('Carol', 'dog-walking'): 2,
    ('Carol', 'painting'): 1
}
```

I am not adding the correct values to my solution and I am having trouble sorting it.

What I have so far:

```
def stats(db1):
    d=defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])
    z=1
    for nametuple, expertlevel in db1.items():
        d[nametuple[0]][0]+=1
        if  d[nametuple[0]][1]==0:
            d[nametuple[0]][1]+=expertlevel
        else:
            d[nametuple[0]][1]+=expertlevel/z
            z+=1
    #return d
    return sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-[x][0],x[1],d))
print(stats(db1))
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track and I like the `defaultdict` approach. If you decouple the averaging step from the aggregation step, you may find the logic easier to manage.

The intermediate dict should contain provider name keys each mapped to a list of service levels. Loop over each person in the dict and take the average of their services to build the result tuples. The number of services offered is implicitly the length of the list.

Sorting is well-defined for tuples (they'll be sorted on the first element by default), so no `key` needs to be specified.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> stats = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in db1.items():
...     stats[k[0]].append(v)
...
>>> sorted((k, len(v), sum(v) / len(v)) for k, v in stats.items())
[('Al', 2, 1.5), ('Bob', 2, 2.0), ('Carol', 3, 1.3333333333333333)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm for mean is incorrect, you need to do this:

```
def stats(db1):
    d=defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])
    for nametuple, expertlevel in db1.items():
        d[nametuple[0]][0]+=1
        d[nametuple[0]][1] = (d[nametuple[0]][1]*(d[nametuple[0]][0]-1)+expertlevel)/d[nametuple[0]][0]

    #return d
    return d.items()
print(stats(db1))
```

Output:

```
dict_items([('Al', [2, 1.5]), ('Bob', [2, 2.0]), ('Carol', [3, 1.3333333333333333])])
```

But a clearer answer could be (edited according to [ggorlen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540775/using-dictionary-to-return-list-of-3-tuples/59541067?noredirect=1#comment105251381_59541067)):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = []
for k,g in groupby(sorted(db1.items()), lambda x:x[0][0]):
    provider = k
    args = list(g)
    services = len(args)
    expertise = sum(elem[1] for elem in args)/services
    lst.append((provider, services, expertise))

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[('Al', 2, 1.5), ('Bob', 2, 2.0), ('Carol', 3, 1.3333333333333333)]
```

Comment: @ggorlen I am sorry I don't follow. Could you give an example?

Comment: Ahh, when you said grouping you meant that! Right, totally slipped my mind. Editing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using list comprehension also:

```
def avg(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

print(sorted([(name,[key[0] for key in db1.keys()].count(name), avg([val for key,val in db1.items() if key[0]==name])) for name in set([key[0] for key in db1.keys()])],key=lambda x: x[0]))

>>>[('Al', 2, 1.5), ('Bob', 2, 2.0), ('Carol', 3, 1.3333333333333333)]
```